# Spring IntegrationFlow for multiple JSON object patterns

Tags: java, json, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-integration

I tried to implement Spring IntegrationFlow to work with AWS SQS queue by setting up poller to poll (JSON) message from the queue periodically and process the message then save to my database.

I successfully poll the single JSON message pattern from queue and transform to my custom object. Now I have 2 type of JSON patterns send to the same SQS queue. For example,

```
`"Type" : "Notification",
"MessageId" : "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
"TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxx:topicName00",
"Subject" : "OK: \"test00\" in US-West-2",
"Message" : "{\"AlarmName\":\"test00\..."`
```

and

```
`"Type" : "Notification",
"MessageId" : "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx",
"TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxx:topicName01",
"Message" : "{\"version\":\"0\",\"id\":\"xxxxx\",\"detail-type\":\"EC2 Instance State-change Notification\",\"source\":\"aws.ec2\..."`
```

These messages are sent to the same queue and I want to poll queue using the same poller then route messages to different transformers and serviceActivator(handle) based on their message body.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sqsIntegrationFlow()
{
    return IntegrationFlows.from( this.sqsMessageSource(), c -> c.poller( myPoller() ) )
            .channel( new DirectChannel() )
            .<Payload,Boolean>route( input -> input.value().contains( "EC2 Instance State-change Notification" ),
                    mapping -> mapping
                            .subFlowMapping( "true", sf -> sf.channel( new DirectChannel() )
                                    .transform(
                                            SqsMessageToInstanceConverter::convertSqsMessagesToInstanceInfo )
                                    .channel( new DirectChannel() ).handle( ( message ) -> {
                                        ec2InstanceService.updateInstanceInfo( (List<SqsMessageResult>) message.getPayload() );
                                    } ) )
                            .subFlowMapping( "false", sf -> sf.channel( new DirectChannel() )
                                    .transform( SqsMessageToInstanceConverter::convertSqsMessageToAlarmInfo )
                                    .channel( new DirectChannel() ).handle( (alarm -> {
                                        cwAlarmService.updateAlarmInfo(
                                                (List<SqsAlarmMessageResult>) alarm.getPayload() );
                                    }) ) ) )
            .get();
}
```

I tried using router as above and identified message using the String in message body ("EC2 Instance State-change Notification") but get error with

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.support.management.MappingMessageRouterManagement`

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to use router?

2. How can I accomplish the goal to process 2 different JSON messages with integration flow?

Comment: Consider to switch to our official Spring Integration AWS extension: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws. We don't have there `SqsMessageSource`, but Message Driven Listener. Although I will be interested where you picked up your SI-AWS solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct (I wrote a similar flow an hour or so ago). It looks like you have some kind of classpath problem - that interface is in the same jar as the routers. Where are you running your app?

Try running with the `-verbose` JVM arg, I just did and got this...

```
...
[Loaded org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter from file:/Users/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar]
[Loaded org.springframework.integration.support.management.MappingMessageRouterManagement from file:/Users/.../.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar]
...
```

Comment: Thank you, Gary. It seems I missed to include the dependency. After adding latest release of spring-integration-core artifact to my pom file, the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException disappear.